# How to set a phase termination to maximum Unimproved Step Count?

Tags: optaplanner

I want to use the `maximumUnimprovedStepCount` termination criterion for a local search phase.

The `unmarshalling` of `solverConfigResource` fails with the error

```
No such field org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.termination.TerminationConfig.maximumUnimprovedStepCount
```

The doc says that this termination does not work for the solver, only for a phase, so I am guessing that the correct resource should be `org. ... .config.termination. ...` (without `solver` in the middle).

But why isn't it getting the right class directly?

This is my minimal solver conf:

```
<solver>
    <scanAnnotatedClasses/>

    <scoreDirectorFactory>
        <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT</scoreDefinitionType>
        <scoreDrl>solver/rules.drl</scoreDrl>
    </scoreDirectorFactory>

    <constructionHeuristic>
        <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT_DECREASING</constructionHeuristicType>
    </constructionHeuristic>

    <termination>
        <secondsSpentLimit>60</secondsSpentLimit>
    </termination>

    <localSearch>
        <termination>
            <maximumUnimprovedStepCount>100</maximumUnimprovedStepCount>
        </termination>
    </localSearch>

</solver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's called `<unimprovedStepCountLimit>` now, see `TerminationConfig.java`:

```
<solver>
  ...
  <localSearch>
    <termination>
      <unimprovedStepCountLimit>...</>
    </>
  </>
</>
```

IIRC it got renamed before the public API & config of 6.1 was finished.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I feel very stupid because you made me realize that I was reading the obsolete doc for version 6.0.1... That explains my "why isn't this working" moments! Reading docs version 6.4 now.